# Grammar of the Openings in Fairy Tales

Tags: grammar, syntax

Which is better in terms of grammar and why, I wonder?

1. > Once upon a time lived King and Queen...
2. > Once upon a time there lived King and Queen...

Comment: Neither is correct. The traditional phraseology is: **Once upon a time there lived a king and queen**. You would not use capitals unless you introduced a specific monarch: **Once upon a time there lived a wise monarch named King John, who ruled the kingdom with the assistance of his Queen, Mary Ann.**

Answer (score 0):

A subject is normally needed for a sentence. "Once upon a time" is not a noun phrase, so can't be a subject.  The verb "lived" needs a dummy subject, and "there" is used, similar to how we say "There is a cat", we can say "There lived a cat..."

The first is not correct grammar.

Also we would probably need an article "...a king and queen".

Comment: Couldn’t “A king and queen” be a subject? If making direct word order, the sentence should be: “A king and queen lived once upon a time...”

Comment: I have found a more expanded answer on the similar topic from you, James K, [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177301/there-verb-is-it-grammatical). So, it feels possible both to include “there” to make it sound tale-like and not include it making it grammatical in a common way. I hope I understand it now.